# Fedora switch GUI/text mode without having to log in

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome

So I do have Fedora 26 with GNOME installed. Now I mostly use text-mode, so I did `systemctl` to make Fedora boot to text mode. Now, sometimes I want to lookup something on the internet, read the emails, so I would `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to get into GUI mode. Unfortunately then I have to type my password in the classic GNOME login screen. Can I somehow turn that off, so I can switch from text mode to GUI without typing the password (when I am doing `Ctrl+Alt+F2` to get from GUI to text mode, then I dont have to type my login and password in text mode)

Comment: I'm confused. After you boot, do you not have to login to your text mode shell? You would stay logged in after that when switching to GUI mode and back. The GUI should behave the same: log in the first time you switch to it, then stay logged in. Do you somehow have to log in every time you switch back to GUI? Is there maybe a "lock after X minutes of inactivity" set in GNOME that would trigger while you are working in text mode?

Comment: Well, I do. I have to type in login and password. Then I want to be able to swtich between text mode and GUI without typing a password when I switch from text to GUI mode. And I changed the screen to not lock after 5 minutes, or anything like this

Comment: Is something like GNOME shell not available?  It seems odd that you'd give up so much for something that is virtually the same.